# pushing tty output to node

Tags: bash, node.js, tty

For the satisfaction of my curiosity gene i'd like to play with bash/node combo. 
I don't know how to make those 2 talk together. I just had a great smile on my face finding about [TTY.JS](http://thechangelog.com/post/17152659182/tty-js-terminal-in-your-browser-using-node-js-and-socket) ;-)

How do I feed terminal's output (sdtout?) to node? I thought about redirecting the stream to file and read it with node through 'fs' module. But there must be some prettier way I bet

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should send terminal output to node

```
var app = require('express').createServer(),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    sys = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec;

app.listen(4990);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('console', function(command, callBack) {
        // client sends {command: 'ls -al'}
        function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
            socket.emit('commandresult', stdout);
        }
        exec(command.command, puts);
    });
});​
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It did, it did indeed ;-) Thank you!